# How to match different groups in regex

Tags: regex, ruby, capture-group

I have the following string:

```
"Josua de Grave* (1643-1712)"
```

Everything before the `*` is the person's name, the first date `1634` is his birth date, `1712` is the date of his death.

Following this logic I'd like to have 3 match groups for each one of the item. I tried

```
([a-zA-Z|\s]*)\* (\d{3,4})-(\d{3,4})
```

```
"Josua de Grave* (1643-1712)".match(/([a-zA-Z|\s]*)\* (\d{3,4})-(\d{3,4})/)
```

but that returns nil.

Why is my logic wrong, and what should I do to get the 3 intended match groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional brackets `(` `)` around the digit `1643-1712` values needs to be added in your regex pattern so use

```
([a-zA-Z\s]*)\* \((\d{3,4})-(\d{3,4})\)
//               ^^                   ^^
```

since brackets represents the captured group so escape them using `\` to match them as a character.

Comment: Be careful using `\s` as it matches more than a space: `/[ \t\r\n\f\v]/`. Also, it's not necessary to use the alternate `|` inside `[``]`.

Comment: @theTinMan `\s` is the requirement to match the spaces though I also missed to see `|` in pattern as it will match `|` char which is less likely but still why have it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* use a pattern, the problem of splitting this into its parts can also be easily done using other Ruby methods:

Using `split`:

```
s = "Josua de Grave* (1643-1712)"
name, dates = s.split('*') # => ["Josua de Grave", " (1643-1712)"]
birth, death = dates[2..-2].split('-') # => ["1643", "1712"]
```

Or, using `scan`:

```
*name, birth, death = s.scan(/[[:alnum:]]+/) # => ["Josua", "de", "Grave", "1643", "1712"]
name.join(' ')  # => "Josua de Grave"
birth # => "1643"
death # => "1712"
```

If I was using a pattern, I'd use this:

```
name, birth, death = /^([^*]+).+?(\d+)-(\d+)/.match(s)[1..3] # => ["Josua de Grave", "1643", "1712"]
name # => "Josua de Grave"
birth # => "1643"
death # => "1712"
```

`/(^[^*]+).+?(\d+)-(\d+)/` means:

- `^` start at the beginning of the buffer
- `([^*]+)` capture everything *not* `*`, where it'll stop capturing
- `.+?` skip the minimum until...
- `(\d+)` the year is matched and captured
- `-` match but don't capture
- `(\d+)` the year is matched and captured

[Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%28%5E%5B%5E*%5D%2B%29.%2B%5C%28%28%5Cd%2B%29-%28%5Cd%2B%29) helps explain it as does [Rubular](https://rubular.com/r/Tb29HTnhTVcEVL).

Comment: love that Regexper thing !

Comment: `[^*]` will match anything till `*` so OP might not want to match everything so OP might not want this, likely only alphabets and spaces also the same with `.*+` which will have more widespread support for input.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /\*\s+\(|(?<=\d)\s*-\s*|\)/

"Josua de Grave* (1643-1712)".split r
  #=> ["Josua de Grave", "1643", "1712"] 

"Sir Winston Leonard Spencer-Churchill* (1874 - 1965)".split r
  #=> ["Sir Winston Leonard Spencer-Churchill", "1874", "1965"]
```

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing* mode:

```
r = /
    \*\s+\(  # match '*' then >= 1 whitespaces then '('
    |        # or
    (?<=\d)  # match is preceded by a digit (positive lookbehind)
    \s*-\s*  # match >= 0 whitespaces then '-' then >= 0 whitespaces 
    |        # or
    \)       # match ')'
    /x       # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

The *positive lookbehind* is needed to avoid splitting hyphenated names on hyphens. (The *positive lookahead* `(?=\d)`, placed after `\s*-\s*`, could be used instead.)